# Integrating a complicated function using Stokes' Theorem

Tags: vector-analysis

$$\vec{\phi}(x,y,z)=\biggl(\frac{\ln(x^5y^3z^2+1)}{z^7+y^4+5}-yx^2e^{2z}, \ \ \cos^2(\pi z)xy^2, \ \ e^{x^2y^2}+\cos z\sin z^3 \biggr)$$

Then let $S$ be the upper-hemisphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ with outward $\vec{n}$. Using Stokes' Theorem, find $$\iint_S(\nabla \ \times \ \vec{\phi})\cdot d\vec{S}$$

What do I do to make this easier to integrate?

Comment: Poor Stokes, people call him Stoke all the time...

Comment: I have seen Strokes too ! :P

Comment: Do you mean $\nabla\times \phi$? Did you try to use Stokes' theorem?

Comment: @TrevorNorton Yes? No, I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: Instead of calculating the surface integral of $(\nabla \times \phi)\cdot d S$ over the hemisphere, you can calculate the integral $\phi\cdot d s$ over the boundary (here that's the circle $z=0$ and $x^2+y^2=4$). Can you set up this line integral?

Comment: @TrevorNorton. I'm unsure of how to do that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stokes' Theorem allows us to write surface integrals of the curl of a vector field $\nabla \times \vec{F}$ into line integrals of the vector field around the boundary, i.e., $\iint_S(\nabla\times\vec F)\cdot d\vec S = \oint_{\partial S} \vec F \cdot d \vec s$. Here the boundary of the hemisphere is the circle $C$ of radius $2$ in the $xy$- plane: $\{(x,y,0) \mid x^2 + y^2 =4 \}$. So we need to set up the line integral $\oint_C\vec \phi \cdot d \vec s$.

We can parameterize $C$ by $r(t) = (2\cos t , 2 \sin t, 0)$ for $t\in [0,2\pi]$. I'll show how to set up the integral, but I'll put a spoiler tag on it in case you want to try setting it up from here.

Setting up the integral:

> We have that $r'(t) = (-2\sin t, 2\cos t, 0)$. So \begin{aligned}\oint_C \vec \phi \cdot d \vec s &= \int_0^{2\pi}\vec\phi(r(t)) \cdot r'(t)\, d t \\ &= \int_0^{2pi}(-(2\sin t) (\cos t)^2, (2\sin t)^2 (2\cos t), e^{16\cos^2 t \sin^2 t}) \cdot (-2\sin t, 2 \cos t, 0)\,  dt \\ &= 2 \int_0^{2\pi}(4\sin t\cos t)^2 dt.\end{aligned} From here, we can use standard integration techniques and trig identities to evaluate the integral.

Comment: Thank you! But there's apparently an easier way to get it to the form of double integrals in polar coordinates and $r^3$ is what you're integrating. I don't know the steps to get it to that form though.

Comment: @sucksatmath I'm skeptical there's an easier way than this. I think trying to change the variables in the double integral is going to be a bit of challenge. But if you found a way to make it work then good for you. :)